# Target Undefined When Right Clicking In Firefox With Context Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using code to create a custom context menu. Its working however there is an issue in Firefox. When right clicking on either a Select box/dropdown list or a button it gives me the following error in Firefox:

```
TypeError: this.target is undefined
[Break On This Error]   Filtered chrome url chrome://browser/content/nsContextMenu.js
nsContextMenu.js (line 162)
TypeError: gContextMenu is null
```

The following code works in Chrome and Internet Explorer but gives an error in Firefox:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){
        if($(e.target).prop("tagName")=="A"){
         //do something
        }
});
```

Note that this error only happens in Firefox so far with the following tags when right clicking on them.

```
<select>
<button> 
<input type='checkbox'>
```

Text boxes work fine however.

Edit: Ok it seems even with no code inside "contextmenu" function it still gives the error.

## Update: This appears to be a Firebug issue in Firefox as no erros appear using Firefox's Developer tools javascript console.

Comment: This does look like the right code, can you double check?

Comment: I don't see `this.target` in your code. Which line is line 162? My guess is that you're having `this.target` where it should be `e.target`.

Comment: I fixed that but still same error.

Comment: *Ok it seems even with no code inside "contextmenu" function it still gives the error.*. You'll have to post the code that throws. Find out in which file, and on which line the error is thrown, and post that code.

Comment: I think I have solved it. It appears to be a Firebug issue and only in FF. If I turn ff off and use Web Developer tools no errors are reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be solved by disabling Firebug. It is a firebug related issue and not a Firefox bug in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using tag name with `DOM` object like this `e.target.tagName`

```
$(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName =="A"){
         //do something
        }
});
```

Comment: That produced the same error as the code I was previously using.